# Algebraic manipulation with indices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is:

For a>0 and $\sqrt{a}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}=3$, find the value of $a\sqrt{a}+\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a}}$

So I first squared the given equation and got:

$$a+\frac{1}{a}+2=9$$
$$a+\frac{1}{a}=7$$

Then to get the form of $a\sqrt{a}+\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a}}$:

$$(a+\frac{1}{a})(\sqrt{a}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}})=a\sqrt{a}+\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a}}+\frac{\sqrt{a}}{a}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{a}}$$

And I just got stuck right here because I didn't really know what to do with the $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{a}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{a}}$. So I looked into the solutions and apparently it's

$$(a+\frac{1}{a})(\sqrt{a}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}})=a\sqrt{a}+\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a}}+\sqrt{a}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$$

I'm not sure how those two are equal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{\sqrt a}a = \frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt a\cdot\sqrt a} = \frac1{\sqrt a}\\
\frac a{\sqrt a} = \frac{\sqrt a\cdot \sqrt a}{\sqrt a} =  \sqrt a
$$
From this we get that "those two" are indeed equal.

The top equality might be worth remembering specifically, because some people prefer to write $\frac1{\sqrt 2}$, while some people prefer to write $\frac{\sqrt2}2$. *Knowing* that it's the same number, without having to check every time, will make reading them faster.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\sqrt{a}$ then $x+\frac{1}{x}=3$ and 
$$
\\a\sqrt{a}+\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a}}=x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=(x+\frac{1}{x})^3-3x\cdot\frac{1}{x}(x+\frac{1}{x})=27-3\cdot3=18
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\sqrt{a}}{a}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{a}}=\sqrt{a}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}=3$ !

Comment: $3!$ is not the right answer (be careful with exclamation marks).